# Reverse Greek Conversion Golf

Tags: code-golf, number, natural-language, conversion

#### Introduction

You must create a function to convert Greek numerals into Arabic numerals. The input will be a Greek numeral less than `1000` and more than `0`. This is the reverse of my [previous challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/78222/greek-conversion-golf).

#### Algorithm

1. Split input into letters (e.g. `ΡΚΓ` -> `Ρ`, `Κ`, `Γ`)
2. Take each letter, and change to character found in table below, for letter symbol, (e.g. `ΡΚΓ` -> `Ρ`, `Κ`, `Γ` -> `100`, `20`, `3`).
3. Add (e.g. `ΡΚΓ` -> `Ρ`, `Κ`, `Γ` -> `100`, `20`, `3` -> `123`)

#### Specifications

- No built-in number-system conversion
- Input will be capitalized as in example.
- Output must be in base 10.
- `ΡΡΡΡ` will never happen. It will be `Υ`.

#### Test Cases

```
ΡΚΓ -> 123
Η -> 8
ΨΟΖ -> 777
Ρ -> 100
ΧϜ -> 606
ΡϘ -> 190
ΜΒ -> 42
Ν -> 50
```

#### Table

```
Α = 1 = Alpha = 913 UTF-8
Β = 2 = Beta = 914 UTF-8
Γ = 3 = Gamma = 915 UTF-8
Δ = 4 = Delta = 916 UTF-8
Ε = 5 = Epsilon = 917 UTF-8
Ϝ = 6 = DiGamma = 988 UTF-8
Ζ = 7 = Zeta = 918 UTF-8
Η = 8 = Eta = 919 UTF-8
Θ = 9 = Theta = 920 UTF-8

Ι = 10 = Iota = 921 UTF-8
Κ = 20 = Kappa = 922 UTF-8
Λ = 30 = Lambda = 923 UTF-8
Μ = 40 = Mu = 924 UTF-8
Ν = 50 = Nu = 925 UTF-8
Ξ = 60 = Xi = 926 UTF-8
Ο = 70 = Omicron = 927 UTF-8
Π = 80 = Pi = 928 UTF-8
Ϙ = 90 = Koppa = 984 UTF-8

Ρ = 100 = Rho = 929 UTF-8   
Σ = 200 = Sigma = 931 UTF-8
Τ = 300 = Tau = 932 UTF-8
Υ = 400 = Upsilon = 933 UTF-8
Φ = 500 = Phi = 934 UTF-8
Χ = 600 = Chi = 935 UTF-8
Ψ = 700 = Psi = 936 UTF-8
Ω = 800 = Omega = 937 UTF-8
Ϡ = 900 = SamPi = 992 UTF-8
```

Comment: Will we ever have input like `ΡΡΡΡ`? If so, what would the result be?

Comment: @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ No. That would be Upsilon.

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood the question, haha.

Comment: @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ I edited that spec in just now. You didn't miss it.

Comment: I think your test cases should cover all possible patterns of zeroes, so at least add something like `180`, `42` and `50`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## [Jelly](http://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>47</s> 45 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
⁵*×‘}
“#'nn(2jj33556;r”Or2/F+878Ọ
¢iÐ€’d9ñ/€S
```

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=4oG1KsOX4oCYfQrigJwjJ25uKDJqajMzNTU2O3LigJ1PcjIvRis4Nzjhu4wKwqJpw5DigqzigJlkOcOxL-KCrFM&input=&args=zqHOms6T) or [verify all test cases](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=4oG1KsOX4oCYfQrigJwjJ25uKDJqajMzNTU2O3LigJ1PcjIvRis4Nzjhu4wKwqJpw5DigqzigJlkOcOxL-KCrFPCteKCrA&input=&args=J86hzprOkycsICfOlycsICfOqM6fzpYnLCAnzqEnLCAnzqfPnCcsICfOoc-YJywgJ86czpInLCAnzp0n).

Comment: What encoding are you using?  Try It Online says it is 47 bytes. You seem to be missing a `<newline>Ç€` at the end.

Comment: Jelly has its own encoding (*bytes* link in the header). The *verify all test cases* link includes an extra `Ç€` that applies the function to all test cases. The first link shows to actual program, which is 44 bytes long.

Comment: This seems to be the shortest so far...

Answer (score 4):

## Python 3, 112

Saved 4 bytes thanks to vaultah.

Booyah, beating JS!

```python
lambda x,z="ΑΒΓΔΕϜΖΗΘΙΚΛΜΝΞΟΠϘΡΣΤΥΦΧΨΩϠ".find:sum((z(c)%9+1)*10**(z(c)//9)for c in x)
```

With test cases:

```python
assert(f("ΡΚΓ")==123)
assert(f("Η")==8)
assert(f("ΨΟΖ")==777)
assert(f("Ρ")==100)
assert(f("ΧϜ")==606)
```

Loops through the string and uses its index in the list of potentials chars to calculate how much it's worth.

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES7), 115 bytes

```js
s=>[...s].map(c=>n+=((i="ΑΒΓΔΕϜΖΗΘΙΚΛΜΝΞΟΠϘΡΣΤΥΦΧΨΩϠ".search(c))%9+1)*10**(i/9|0),n=0)|n
```

Answer (score 3):

### Haskell, <s>116</s> 113 bytes

```
f x=sum[v|d<-x,(l,v)<-zip"ΑΒΓΔΕϜΖΗΘΙΚΛΜΝΞΟΠϘΡΣΤΥΦΧΨΩϠ"$(*)<$>[1,10,100]<*>[1..9],d==l]
```

Usage example: `map f ["ΡΚΓ","Η","ΨΟΖ","Ρ","ΧϜ","ΡϘ","ΜΒ","Ν"]` -> `[123,8,777,100,606,190,42,50]`.

Lookup the value of the greek letter from a list of pairs `(letter, value)` and sum. The list of values is build by `(*)<$>[1,10,100]<*>[1..9]`, where `(*)<$>[1,10,100]` builds a list of functions `[(*1),(*10),(*100)]` (multiply by 1, 10 and 100) which are applied separately to the elements of `[1..9]` and concatenated into a single list.

Edit: 3 bytes with thanks to @xnor.

Comment: It's shorter to take the product as `(*)<$>[1,10,100]<*>[1..9]`.

Comment: @xnor: `<*>` in list context, again. I never think of it myself. Thanks!

Comment: I wouldn't think of it either, I got it from [here](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/52949/20260).

Answer (score 3):

## Julia, <s>82</s> 70 bytes

```
x->10.^((t=findin([1:5;76;6:16;72;17;19:25;80]+912,x)-1)÷9)⋅(t%9+1)
```

[Try it online!](http://julia.tryitonline.net/#code=ZiA9IHgtPjEwLl4oKHQ9ZmluZGluKFsxOjU7NzY7NjoxNjs3MjsxNzsxOToyNTs4MF0rOTEyLHgpLTEpw7c5KeKLhSh0JTkrMSkKCmZvciB4IGluICgizqHOms6TIiwgIs6XIiwgIs6ozp_OliIsICLOoSIsICLOp8-cIiwgIs6hz5giLCAizpzOkiIsICLOnSIpCiAgICBwcmludGxuKGYoeCkpCmVuZA&input=)

Answer (score 2):

### JavaScript (ES6), 116 bytes

```
s=>[...s].map(c=>n+=+((i="ΑΒΓΔΕϜΖΗΘΙΚΛΜΝΞΟΠϘΡΣΤΥΦΧΨΩϠ".search(c))%9+1+"e"+(i/9|0)),n=0)|n
```

Only 1 byte longer than ES7!

Comment: I'm not familiar with JavaScript, what does the `+"e"` do?

Comment: @MorganThrapp String concatenation. For example, with Ϡ you would get `9+"e"+2` and then the `+("9e2")` becomes 900.

Comment: Ah, that's really weird. Javascript always manages to ---terrify--- surprise me.

Answer (score 1):

### Python 3, 188 Bytes

```
def f(x,l=list,z=0):
 r=l(range(1,10));R=[a*10for a in r]
 for a,b in l(zip(l("ΑΒΓΔΕϜΖΗΘΙΚΛΜΝΞΟΠϘΡΣΤΥΦΧΨΩϠ"),r+R+[a*10for a in R])):
  z+=(0,b)[a in x]
 return z
```

[Try it out!](https://repl.it/CIdI/1) (Test cases included)

Comment: You can save 25 bytes by condensing it down to `def f(x):r=list(range(1,10));R=[a*10for a in r];return sum(b*(a in x)for a,b in zip("ΑΒΓΔΕϜΖΗΘΙΚΛΜΝΞΟΠϘΡΣΤΥΦΧΨΩϠ",r+R+[a*10for a in R]))`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Retina](https://github.com/mbuettner/retina), 72 bytes

```
T`_Ι-ΠϘ0ΡΣ-ΩϠ`dl
[a-j]
$0aa 
\d
$&0 
T`_Α-ΕϜΖ-Θl`dd
\d+
$*
1
```

[Try it online.](http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=JShHYApUYF_OmS3OoM-YMM6hzqMtzqnPoGBkbApbYS1qXQokMGFhIApcZAokJjAgClRgX86RLc6Vz5zOli3OmGxgZGQKXGQrCiQqCjE&input=zqHOms6TCs6XCs6ozp_OlgrOoQrOp8-cCs6hz5gKzpzOkgrOnQ)

#### Explanation

Basically - replace every Greek symbol with the number that it represents, then return the sum of all the resulting numbers:

Transliterate `10`s digits to Arabic and `100`s digits to the Latin alphabet (`0`-`9` => `a`-`j`):

```
T`_Ι-ΠϘ0ΡΣ-ΩϠ`dl
```

Append "aa " to any `100`s digits:

```
[a-j]
$0aa
```

Append "0 " to any `10`s digits:

```
\d
$&0
```

Transliterate `1`'s digits and Latin alphabet to Arabic:

```
T`_Α-ΕϜΖ-Θl`dd
```

Convert all space-separated decimal numbers to unary:

```
\d+
$*
```

Count the total number of unary `1`s:

```
1
```